# Calculating address of labels

Tags: architecture, mips, cpu-architecture

I am stuck with solving my assignment. Here is what it states,

> Consider the following fragment of MIPS assembly-language code:

```
start:   add $t1, $t2, $t3
         addi $t1, $t1, 10
         add $t4, $t2, $t2
         add $t6, $t3, $t3
         beq $t1, $t4, q_final
middle:  add $t1, $0, $0
         bne $t6, $t4, s_final
         add $t7, $t7, $t7
j final
q_final: slt $t1, $t4, $t6
s_final: add $t7, $t7, $t1
final:   jr $ra
```

> a) If the label start has the value 100 (all numbers in decimal
>   notation), what are the addresses specified by labels middle, q_final
>   and final?
>   I am confused with how to proceed. I was thinking that adding 4 to each statement would give the value of the other labels. Is there another better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am confused with how to proceed. I was thinking that adding 4 to
>   each statement would give the value of the other labels. Is there
>   another better way of doing this?

Simpler is better (mips!). If each instruction takes 4 bytes, then that´s preety much it.

```
100:     add $t1, $t2, $t3
104:     addi $t1, $t1, 10
108:     add $t4, $t2, $t2
112:     add $t6, $t3, $t3
116:     beq $t1, $t4, 132
120:     add $t1, $0, $0
124:     bne $t6, $t4, 136
128:     add $t7, $t7, $t7

132:     slt $t1, $t4, $t6
136:     add $t7, $t7, $t1
140:     jr $ra
```

By the way, who gives memory addresses in decimal notation?

Comment: That is why I was actually confused. I was wondering if these were actually address or something else.

Comment: Yeap, labels are just memory addresses.

Comment: Can you please elaborate why you did not added the labels?

Comment: added the labels? Im not sure what you mean. I was trying to resemble objdump´s output.